# How is a context diagram different than a level 0 diagram?

Tags: entity-relationship, diagram

What is the difference, if any, between a context diagram and a level 0 diagram?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some conflicts in the literature about these two terms.
Refer page 54 of [this book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ytdKQGJ8f_AC&printsec=frontcover&dq=k%20k%20agarwal&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NnaZUIWcGce8rAeVt4DACg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Context%20diagram&f=false) for example. It is highly rated on google books and is a standard text in many schools. It says that a context diagram is the *same* as a Level 0 DFD. [This one](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=-ot62DeCKO4C&pg=PA208&dq=context%20diagram&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ROKZUKHaJYSzrAfjuoCADg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=context%20diagram&f=false) disagrees on page 210.

I'll first address the notion of "levels".

As we know, initially, the whole of the system is represented by one big block, and interactions with the system are clearly depicted. *Initially, we are seeing the system with a naked eye.*

Now, think of yourself holding something like a microscope. You place the lens above the system block and zoom in. This "zooming in" takes you to the next level in the hierarchy. So now, you see that the system is made up of a number of blocks.

You pick up any of the sub-blocks, and then zoom in again, thus going to the next level and so on.

So we see that there is a hierarchy of diagrams, with each level taking us to the next level of detail. The only bone of contention that now remains is name of the first level (The view with the naked eye).

As you can see, the question is not very objective, hence the ambiguity.

We can have :

```
Context Diagram -> 
                  Level 0 DFD ->
                                    -> Level n DFD</pre>
```

OR

```
Context Diagram/Level 0 DFD 
                              ->Level 1 DFD
                                              ->Level n DFD
```

It boils down to which one looks better. In my personal opinion , the first hierarchy is more apt. This is because initially, all we see is the system and the context within which it operates. I feel that anyone who understands the explanation should't worry much about the nomenclature.

[Refer this](http://www2.mccombs.utexas.edu/courses/mis374/Resources/ProcessModeling/ProcessModelingReading.pdf) for more.

Comment: You sure about that? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram) says "This context-level DFD is next "exploded", to produce a Level 0 DFD that shows some of the detail of the system being modeled"

Comment: There are some ambiguities in the literature. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: There certainly are descriptiveness, my prof told me a context diagram cannot have data stores where as level 0 (and it's children) can.

Comment: That would be case A. It certainly is more suitable. Again, I feel the issue can be ignored once you know the concept.

Comment: (1) the link doesn't work anymore. (2) could someone provide example diagrams for the two types to provide clarify as to what some of the differences could be?

Comment: Great answer. There is no authoritative standard for DFD. Worth to mention: the pioneers of structured analysis and DFD, Gane&Sarson and Demarco don't speak of context diagram. They start immediately with top level diagrams. Demarco called it level 0 for consistency with the numbering scheme: in level 0 the processes are numbered 1, 2, 3, level 1 diagrams decompose any off those into 1.1, 1.2, ...2.1, 2.2, etc. the numbering of the level indicates the level of decomposition compared to the top (and hence the number of suffixes in the decimal numbering of the processes)

Answer (score 1):

A very difficult discussion. 
My thoughts: 
A context diagram only has 1 process, while a DFD level 0 **can** have more.

Answer (score 1):

The context diagram established context at the system to be developed that is it represents the interaction at the system with various external entities.
Where data flow diagram is a simple graphical notation that can be used to represent a system in the term of input data to the system,various processing carried out on this data and the output generated by the system. It is simple to understand and use.